# Remove root@localhost from e-mail's headers

Tags: email, postfix

I am trying to install an e-mail server in my CentOS server. I have installed and configured postfix and bind, but when I send e-mails I still get "root@localhost" and 127.0.0.1 in my e-mail's headers.

I edited `/etc/hosts`, `hostname` and `/etc/postfix/main.cf` but still the same problem.

This is the header I get:

```
Received: from mail.iituness.com (iituness.com [192.162.68.128])
by yen.roundsphere.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id C4E093A38009
for <best@www.brandonchecketts.com>; Sat, 12 Jan 2013 19:33:26 -0500 (EST)
Received: from iituness.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
by mail.iituness.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 3295E330E907
for <best@www.brandonchecketts.com>; Sun, 13 Jan 2013 03:33:26 +0300 (MSK)
Received: (from root@localhost)
by iituness.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id r0D0XQSo003822
for best@www.brandonchecketts.com; Sun, 13 Jan 2013 03:33:26 +0300
```

How do I remove root@localhost from headers?

Comment: First, can you add the contents of your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to the question? Second, what program are you using to send mail? Does it properly fill in the "From" address field?